# mvn command on windows via Github actions throwing syntax error

Tags: powershell, maven, github-actions

Maven Build on windows machine (powershell) via Github action  throwing Syntax of the command is incorrect error, below is the code

```
$args - > "-Dkeystore.filename=E:\LOCAL.Public.p12" "-nsu" "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=NONE" "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=Window" "-D javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL" "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows" "-DMULE_LOG_BASE=E:\log"

mvn clean package -s "Devops-Framework\config\mvn_settings.xml" "-Dserver.username=${{inputs.JFROG_USER}}" "-Dserver.password=${{inputs.JFROG_APIKEY}}" $args
```

throws The syntax of the command is incorrect.
What is wrong in the formatting of the below command? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need [spatting your args with an array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3#splatting-with-arrays):

```
$args = @("-Dkeystore.filename=E:\LOCAL.Public.p12", "-nsu", "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=NONE", "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=Window", "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL", "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows", "-DMULE_LOG_BASE=E:\log")

mvn clean package -s "Devops-Framework\config\mvn_settings.xml" "-Dserver.username=${{inputs.JFROG_USER}}" "-Dserver.password=${{inputs.JFROG_APIKEY}}" @args
```